# Stack resolution in stack

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-stack

I have a deck, and it involves [Murderous Redcap](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370518), [Viscera Seer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bViscera%20Seer%5d), and [Geralf's Messenger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGeralf%27s%5d%2b%5bMessenger%5d). I was to sacrifice the Redcap and Messenger, remove a +1/+1 counter from the Messenger using [Retribution of the Ancients](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRetribution%20of%20the%20Ancients%5d) in response to someone trying to kill my Viscera Seer?

The idea is that, I play Redcap, sacrifice it with the Seer, someone tries to bolt my Seer. Can I, in response, continue my combination of sacrificing the Messenger, moving the counter to the Redcap, and sacrificing them both again before the [Lightning Bolt](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLightning%20Bolt%5d) resolves?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the part where you "negate the -1/-1 using Retribution of the Ancients"? I'm assuming you want to eliminate the -1/-1 counter on the Murderous Redcap, but that would be done by putting a +1/+1 counter on it, and Retribution of the Ancients gives a creature -X/-X, which is a totally different effect.

Comment: You seem to maybe be misreading Retribution of the Ancients. It removes a +1/+1 counter, it does NOT move a counter to another creature.

Comment: @Malco I checked the links after my edit with the rollover Tampermonkey extension; can it happen that the rollover works, but clicking the link doesn't?

Comment: @GendoIkari The rollover is a browser extension right? It is likely that your roll-over tool uses different logic than the mtg-autocard, but the issue with Murderous Redcap not working is a known one as the Autocard breaks on cards that have similarly named avatar cards. See [this meta post](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1525/autocard-not-working-for-platinum-angel) for more info.

Comment: @Malco Thanks. I knew about the avatar card issue; I just didn't realize that checking the rollover wasn't enough. Yes, it's a browser extension that lets you see the card without clicking the link.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I did misinterpret that, but I have the Retribution combo'ing with the Messengers and I have a Solemnity working with Redcaps. I was asking about a possible way that my combo could be stopped, and the answer below helps point it out.

Comment: But the question still stands, if a lightning bolt were cast when I specified, can I continue to combo off?

Comment: " if a lightning bolt were cast when I specified" You didn't specify when the bolt was cast, though. All you said was "Someone tries to bolt my Seer". The question depends completely on exactly when the bolt was cast. What event is your opponent responding to?

Comment: @GendoIkari after I choose to sacrifice the Redcap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While some other parts of your question are of debatable veracity, the core seems to be this:

> I play Redcap, sacrifice it with the Seer, someone tries to bolt my Seer.

Assuming that your opponent has a firm understanding of the stack, they will cast Lightning Bolt before the Persist trigger of the Redcap resolves; at that point the Redcap will be in your graveyard and it will not leave the graveyard until after the Lightning Bolt resolves. You cannot continue to sacrifice the Redcap in this situation. It isn't impossible for an opponent to wait for your Redcap to return before casting their spell, but it seems unlikely that one choose to do so.

---

As requested, if someone DOES cast Lightning Bolt while Murderous Redcap is on the battlefield, assuming (per an earlier comment) that you have Solemnity or some other combo piece rather than Retribution of the Ancients in order to make the combo repeatable, you can continue to combo in response to the Bolt. Lightning Bolt does not have Split Second so you are allowed to activate any ability or cast any spell which is not prevented by some other rule or effect. There is also no requirement that you allow the Lightning Bolt to resolve in order for later effects to resolve. Unless your combo requires *casting* a spell with a timing restriction, such as a sorcery, or activating an ability with a timing restriction, which will be stated in the ability's description, Lightning Bolt being on the stack will not restrict the combo at all.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am still curious about the original question, which is if someone were to bolt my seer when my creature returns, can I continue my combo?

Comment: @Ice76 It is unclear what the full combo you are trying to do is. Can you explain (by editing your question) what the end result you are trying to achieve is?